# Create Record With "has_many_through" Association – Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, has-many-through

I have a `has_many_through` association where `User`s have many `Project`s through `ProjectUser`s. Rails has some magic that allows updating this relationship with:

```
u = User.first
u.update(project_ids: [...])
```

Is there a clean way to do the same thing with `create`?

Running `User.create(name: ..., project_ids: [...])` fails with `Validation failed: Project users is invalid`.

I suspect this is because Rails tries to create the `ProjectUser` record before creating the `User` record and has some built-in validation on join tables to validate that both sides of the join already exist. The `ProjectUser` model has no custom validation.

```
class ProjectUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Is there a simple way to get around this?

Comment: The reason you are thinking of is wrong. You need to give all attributes for `User` model like `User.create!(name: "xxx", project_ids: [...])`

Comment: @titan2gman Sorry for the confusion. I've been passing other params, but I omitted them for the sake of keeping the question concise. I updated the question

Comment: Are you sure all ids from `project_ids` array exit in `projects` table?

Comment: @titan2gman Yep! The same command works if create the `User` record first and then update using the same array of `project_ids`

Comment: You can check an answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Active Record supports automatic identification for most associations with standard names. However, Active Record will not automatically identify bi-directional associations that contain the :through or :foreign_key options.* (You can check [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/active_record/reflection.rb#L586))

So you have to define `inverse_of` explicitly.

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :project_users, foreign_key: :project_id, inverse_of: :project
  has_many :users, through: :project_users
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :project_users, foreign_key: :user_id, inverse_of: :user
  has_many :projects, through: :project_users
end

class ProjectUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally people use hmt (instead of `has_and_belongs_to_many`) because they have other fields that they're interested in populating in the join table, hence people usually create the triplet of model records using the join table, eg.

```rb
ProjectUser.create! the_extra_field: "Foo", user: User.create!(name: "Jim"), project: Project.create!(title: "Project X")
```

Obviously if you already have an existing `User` or `Project` then you'd use those instead of creating new ones.

Answer (score -2):

I believe that you need to use [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :project_users
  has_many :projects, through: :project_users

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :projects
end
```

That must help you to create users with associated projects like you expected

```
User.create(name: 'John', project_ids: [...])
```